# Query parameters removal and refreshModel

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

So I have this application with a page which contains a list that can be filtered.

The data behind the list can be VERY big, so the filtering is done server-side by sending filter parameters, very similar to what is found in the JSONAPI reference (e.g. `?filter[name]=John&filter[date]=2016-09-12|2016-09-15`).

In order to do that, I have set up my route as follows:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend(AuthenticatedRoute, {
  queryParams: {
    'filter[name]': {
      refreshModel: true
    },
    [...]
  },

  model(params) {
    return this.store.query('receipt', params);
  }
});
```

Which make the route copy its query parameter to the API call without any issues.

Now, of course, the user must be able to change the filters from his interface, right? So I made a little Bootstrap modal/form and hooked it up with an action in my controller, which builds a set of query parameters and reloads the route with them:

```
changeFilters() {
  var params = {};
  if (this.get('nameFilter')) {
    params['filter[name]'] = this.get('nameFilter');
  }
  [...]
  this.transitionToRoute({queryParams: params});
}
```

Doing this does actually work fine. When the `filter[name]` parameter is added or changed in the query, the route refreshes and updates the model. However, the problem comes when the user disables the filter: it seems that removing the query parameter doesn't refreshes the route even with `refreshModel` set to true.

So, I am pretty sure it is a bug, as it doesn't make any sense to me, but in the meantime I am quite new to Ember so I thought I would ask for help here before filing a bug report.

So is there something I am missing? Or is this by design/some kind of design limitation?

Thanks!

Comment: just thought, instead removal just set it to default value empty `''` that will reload that's how i am doing for my queryParams.

Comment: Oh yeah, that's what I've done in the meantime, the parameter is not removed and the `refreshModel` fires a refresh but that's not very optimal. It's not a big deal for the moment (except the ugly URL it produces), but an empty string is not really the same thing as a undefined/null string and I can see it becoming a problem on certain fields. For VAT numbers for example, I want `filter[vat]=` to filter only receipts with no (blank) VAT numbers, but I still want to be able to disable the filtering altogether.

Comment: @blue This issue: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/10577 might be helpful? Query params are really tricky; I'm not sure if this is a bug or not. As a workaround, you could try sending an action from your controller to trigger a refresh in your route: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_refresh

Comment: @MaxWallace This is not really the same issue I am encountering, but I think that the workaround posted in the last comment can definitely help me. The queryParamsDidChange method has access to removed items, so I can probably build something on top of that. It is a bit hacky though, as the method is private, but this `removed` argument looks very promising. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if, instead of using `transitionToRoute`, you update the query params via bindings on your controller?

The code would look like:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({

  queryParams: {
    'filter[name]': {
      refreshModel: true
    },
  },

});
```

and

```
changeFilters() {
  var params = {};
  if (this.get('nameFilter')) {
    this.set('filter[name]', this.get('nameFilter'));
  }
  [...]
}
```

I'm not sure if this will work, but you could give it a shot.

Comment: The problem with this is that changing attributes in the controller won't change the URL, and I want my clients to be able to share the URL between each other, filters included. Maybe some sort of hybrid could work, but even then I don't think setting the `filter[name]` attribute in the controller will automatically set it in the route.

Comment: @blue The guides say that changing the attribute in the controller will update the URL: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.8.0/routing/query-params/#toc_specifying-query-parameters -- "...any changes to the category query param in the URL will update the category property on controller:articles, and vice versa."